# Get new prototype from XML for playlist-items

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to pull playlist data from an XML file and create new playlist items in json format. jPlayer is used for the audio playback/playlist and the xml2json plugin to convert the XML.

I'm having trouble with inserting each individual track + data as a playlist item. Also I wonder if using the prototype method is the right thing to do for this purpose.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //define object for individual tracks
    var $track = {
        mp3Location : "path/to/mp3",
        oggLocation : "path/to/ogg",
        creator     : "Daisha de Wijs",
        album   : "Programmanaam",
        title       : "Onderwerp",
        annotation  : "Beschrijving",
        poster  : "path/to/img" 
        }
    //create prototype for track object 
    function Track (track) {
        this.track = track;
        };  
    Track.prototype = $track;
    //read XML file and pull contents
    //Example XML contents
    //<track>
//      <mp3Location>http://www.rmuitzendinggemist.nl/uitzendinggemist/gezondheid1x02.mp3</mp3Location>
//      <oggLocation>http://www.rmuitzendinggemist.nl/uitzendinggemist/gezondheid1x02.ogg</oggLocation>
//            <creator>Daisha de Wijs</creator>
//            <album>Gezondheid</album>
//            <title>Blauwe bessen en meer</title>
//            <annotation>Je bent overtuigd vegetariër of veganist en wil niets dierlijks eten.</annotation>
//            <image>http://www.radiomerlijn.nl/images/stories/pics/Blauwe_bessen.jpg</image>
//        </track>
    $.get('xml/GezondheidList.xml', function (xml) {
        var $track = $.xml2json(xml);
        //use xml2json to convert each <track> into track[n] json object
        });
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: track1.mp3location,
            ogg: track1.oggLocation
          });
        },
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3, ogg"
      });
    var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer : "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "jp_container_1"
        }, [], {});
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
    //load json objects from $tracks
    $tracks.val()
    ]); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your code relates, you define a constructor function called Track but never use it. Then use an XHR to set a value $track that's never used and then on document load you're loading $tracks that's never set. You seem to define instance specific values on the prototype, maybe define them as `this.mp3location=...` in the constructor function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! The $tracks variable should be $track(typo). I will go ahead and define the values in the constructor function as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that may be a problem is that you load xml and create the player on 2 separate occasions. There is no guarantee that the xml file has loaded when you try to set the playlist. Maybe change the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
//.... other code
$.get('xml/GezondheidList.xml').then(
  function (xml) {
    var $track = $.xml2json(xml);
    console.log($track);
    //use xml2json to convert each <track> into track[n] json object
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
      //load json objects from $tracks
      $track.val()
    ]);
  },function(e){
    //$.get error
    console.log("an error:",e);
  }
);
```

I added some console.log statements. In Chrome you can press F12 to open the developer tools and check out the console tab. You can click on logged objects to inspect the details. If you have Firefox you can install the Firebug plugin and open it with F12. That logs click able object details as well.